# If $R{^m}$ is isomorphic to $R{^n}$ as $R$-modules and if $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ then how can I show that image of $M{^m}$ is $M{^n}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> If $R{^m}$ is isomorphic to $R{^n}$ as $R$-modules and if $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ then how can I show that image of $M{^m}$ is $M{^n}$?

Background: I was trying to prove that if $R{^m}$  is isomorphic to $R{^n}$ as $R$-modules then $m=n$. For this I need a step like $R{^m/M{^m}}$ isomorphic to $R{^n/M{^n}}$.

I need some help. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at a much more general statement: For any ideal $I\subset R$, and any homomorphism $f: N\to N'$ of $R$-modules, $f(IN) \subset IN'$.  This statement is immediate from the definition of a module homomorphism.

If $f$ is an isomorphism, then we can apply the same claim to $f^{-1}$, and see that $f$ restricts to an isomorphism $IN\to IN'$.  Setting $I=M$, $N=R^m$, $N'=R^n$ gives what you want.

Comment: But how $M(R{^m})=M{^m}$?

Comment: @Via Do you know the definition of $IN$?  It's the module generated by elements of the form $rn$, with $r\in R$, $n\in N$.  In other words, it's the sum of all such products.  Given an element in $I^m$, can you see how to write it this way?

Comment: yea I got..I am fool..thanks for ur perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Let  $f:R^n\rightarrow R^m$ be an isomorphism. Consider $\overline{f}:(R/M)^n\rightarrow (R/N)^m$ given by $\overline{f}([r])=f(r)$ (the map is clearly well-defined). Proceeding in an  analogue way  we can construct $\overline{f^{-1}}$. It is clear that  $\overline{f^{-1}}$ is the inverse of $\overline{f}$.

Comment: Actually I am trying to prove finally what U gave me as a hint

Comment: @Via I added more details.

Comment: I was following the pdf http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gor/Math323_2013/323hw9_sol.pdf @sec10.3 prob 2.For which I need to prove it independently of the above isomorphism.