# Question on a proof of $\Bbb Z^n \cong \Bbb Z^m \implies n=m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I've read the following argument (on Wikipedia, IIRC) :

> Suppose that $\Bbb Z^n \cong \Bbb Z^m$ as abelian groups. Then quotienting both sides by $(2\Bbb Z)^n$ and $(2\Bbb Z)^m$ respectively, we get the group isomorphism $\Bbb F_2^n \cong \Bbb F_2^m$, which implies $2^n=2^m$ i.e. $n=m$ [NB : we just compare cardinalities, we can't conclude $n=m$ because of some *vector space* isomorphism].

I have the following question :
Why can we ensure that the image of $(2\Bbb Z)^n$ under the given isomorphism is $(2\Bbb Z)^m$ ? I want to use $A/I \cong B/f(I)$, where $f : A \to B$ is an injective group morphism. But I don't know how.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if you have other proofs of $\Bbb Z^n \cong \Bbb Z^m \implies n=m$, I would be interested :-)

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't hold for modules over any ring $R$. See invariant basis number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number

Comment: Z^0 is not isomorphic to Z^(0+k) for all k (by cardinality difference). Assume Z^n is not isomorphic to Z^(n+k). Z^n*Z is not isomorphic to Z^(n+k)*Z because otherwise the isomorphism truncated to Z_n would be an isomorphism to Z^(n+k).

Comment: I found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989944

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi:\mathbb Z^n\to\mathbb Z^m$ is an isomorphism, then $\forall x\in\mathbb Z^n$, $\phi(2x) = \phi(x+x) = \phi(x)+\phi(x) = 2\phi(x)$ so the restriction of $\phi$ to $2(\mathbb Z^n)=(2\mathbb Z)^n$ is an isomorphism onto $2(\mathbb Z^m)=(2\mathbb Z)^m$.

Comment: What did you prove?!

Comment: @user26857 I don't see $n=m$ in his answer!

Comment: @Ab_Sh, why didn't you just read the question: "I have the following question : Why can we ensure that the image of $(2\mathbb Z)^n$ under the given isomorphism is $(2\mathbb Z)^m$ ? "

Comment: @Ennar Thanks, so I should read the question and not the answer! (see the comment of user26857)